# Need to simulate tab change scenario from an android test project

Tags: android

In my app, I've got 3 tabs. On clicking on each individual tab, some tab specific task happens. Now I am supposed to test the scenario of changing tabs from an android test project. In order to do that, I've called getTabHost.setCurrentTab(int tabIndex) method. But an error has been thrown saying

**android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is quite self explanatory: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." In other words, you're trying to change the current tab from a different thread than the one that created it. More specifically, you have to do this action on the widget from the GUI thread - the thread that created the view hierarchy.

So you either have to move your `setCurrentTab(int tabIndex)` call to the GUI thread, or use a message mechanism. The latter is usually done using a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Plenty of good examples and code snippets 'out there' that can show you how to go about this.